# Need crash dump translation

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-crash

The following is a crash dump I get which is resulted from an Java application crash.  Does anyone have any idea of how to get around this situation?  I can't get much out of this.  It could be due to my limited experience.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x49a729a0, pid=3092, tid=3244
#
# JRE version: 7.0_04-b22
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.0-b21 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x49a729a0
#
# Core dump written. Default location: C:\Program Files\iDATest\hs_err_pid3092.mdmp
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x49e0e000):  JavaThread "pool-21-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=3244, stack(0x4aae0000,0x4ab30000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x00000008 0x49a729a0

Registers:
EAX=0x74bda8cd, EBX=0x0072c068, ECX=0x0000000b, EDX=0x00000000
ESP=0x4ab2def0, EBP=0x4ab2def8, ESI=0x00bba6b8, EDI=0xffffffff
EIP=0x49a729a0, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x4ab2def0)
0x4ab2def0:   754760ad 7fffffff 4ab2df30 74bce956
0x4ab2df00:   74bda8cd 00000000 4ab2dfcc 4ab2dfbc
0x4ab2df10:   00000000 00000000 ffffffff ffffffff
0x4ab2df20:   00000000 0072c068 74bda8cd 75476085
0x4ab2df30:   4ab2e01c 74bc6d30 00000878 00000410
0x4ab2df40:   01000001 00000004 07696daf 00bb8ba0
0x4ab2df50:   00000000 00000000 00000000 0000001c
0x4ab2df60:   00bb8ba0 00000000 75466a41 4ab2e080 

Instructions: (pc=0x49a729a0)
0x49a72980:   20 00 68 00 61 00 6e 00 64 00 6c 00 65 00 20 00
0x49a72990:   69 00 73 00 20 00 6e 00 6f 00 77 00 20 00 61 00
0x49a729a0:   73 00 73 00 6f 00 63 00 69 00 61 00 74 00 65 00
0x49a729b0:   64 00 20 00 77 00 69 00 74 00 68 00 20 00 61 00 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x74bda8cd is an unknown value
EBX=0x0072c068 is an unknown value
ECX=0x0000000b is an unknown value
EDX=0x00000000 is an unknown value
ESP=0x4ab2def0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x49e0e000
EBP=0x4ab2def8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x49e0e000
ESI=0x00bba6b8 is an unknown value
EDI=0xffffffff is an unknown value


Stack: [0x4aae0000,0x4ab30000],  sp=0x4ab2def0,  free space=311k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x49a729a0
C  [mswsock.dll+0xe956]  MigrateWinsockConfiguration+0x1c2f
C  [mswsock.dll+0x6d30]
C  [WS2_32.dll+0x6a28]  select+0x9f
C  [net.dll+0x3d94]  NET_Timeout+0x59

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[BIII)I+0
j  java.net.SocketInputStream.read([BIII)I+79
j  java.net.SocketInputStream.read([BII)I+11
j  sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Ljava/io/InputStream;[BII)I+21
j  sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/io/OutputStream;)V+32
j  sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Lsun/security/ssl/InputRecord;Z)V+44
j  sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Lsun/security/ssl/InputRecord;)V+15
j  sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read([BII)I+72
j  sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes()I+135
j  sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead([CII)I+112
j  sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read([CII)I+180
j  java.io.InputStreamReader.read([CII)I+7
j  java.io.BufferedReader.fill()V+145
J  java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Z)Ljava/lang/String;
j  java.io.BufferedReader.readLine()Ljava/lang/String;+2
j  org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply(Z)V+16
j  org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__getReply()V+2
j  org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I+36
j  org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sendCommand(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I+3
j  org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/net/Socket;+359
j  org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/InputStream;)Z+3
j  org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.__storeFile(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/io/InputStream;)Z+7
j  org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/InputStream;)Z+5
j  com.iwebgate.ida.execution.ftp.Uploader.ftp(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Z+475
J  com.iwebgate.ida.execution.PortalExtractor.call()Ljava/lang/Exception;
j  com.iwebgate.ida.execution.PortalExtractor.call()Ljava/lang/Object;+1
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun()V+29
j  java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run()V+4
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker;)V+46
j  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run()V+5
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x49e0e000 JavaThread "pool-21-thread-1" [_thread_in_native, id=3244, stack(0x4aae0000,0x4ab30000)]
  0x49e0c400 JavaThread "IDAScheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=4064, stack(0x4afe0000,0x4b030000)]
  0x49e0c000 JavaThread "IDAScheduler_Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2308, stack(0x4b300000,0x4b350000)]
  0x49e0b400 JavaThread "TimerQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1600, stack(0x4af10000,0x4af60000)]
  0x49481400 JavaThread "Swing-Shell" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3240, stack(0x4aa70000,0x4aac0000)]
  0x492e6400 JavaThread "derby.rawStoreDaemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=728, stack(0x49c60000,0x49cb0000)]
  0x493abc00 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3248, stack(0x49c10000,0x49c60000)]
  0x009fa800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=1528, stack(0x00af0000,0x00b40000)]
  0x49239000 JavaThread "AWT-EventQueue-0" [_thread_blocked, id=3352, stack(0x49a20000,0x49a70000)]
  0x49236800 JavaThread "AWT-Windows" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2532, stack(0x003e0000,0x00430000)]
  0x49235c00 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=1468, stack(0x49b60000,0x49bb0000)]
  0x49233400 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4068, stack(0x49970000,0x499c0000)]
  0x010f5400 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2724, stack(0x490d0000,0x49120000)]
  0x010eb400 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3236, stack(0x48f00000,0x48f50000)]
  0x010ea400 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2396, stack(0x012e0000,0x01330000)]
  0x010e7000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2200, stack(0x48e50000,0x48ea0000)]
  0x01093800 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2292, stack(0x48eb0000,0x48f00000)]
  0x00cdcc00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2948, stack(0x00790000,0x007e0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x00cd7c00 VMThread [stack: 0x00a40000,0x00a90000] [id=1400]
  0x01110800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x49070000,0x490c0000] [id=2508]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 18603K [0x04760000, 0x068c0000, 0x194b0000)
  eden space 27392K,  65% used [0x04760000, 0x058ff8c8, 0x06220000)
  from space 3392K,  16% used [0x06220000, 0x062ab348, 0x06570000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x06570000, 0x06570000, 0x068c0000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 16166K [0x194b0000, 0x1d760000, 0x42f60000)
   the space 68288K,  23% used [0x194b0000, 0x1a479ab8, 0x1a479c00, 0x1d760000)
 compacting perm gen  total 22016K, used 21878K [0x42f60000, 0x444e0000, 0x46f60000)
   the space 22016K,  99% used [0x42f60000, 0x444bd938, 0x444bda00, 0x444e0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Code Cache  [0x02760000, 0x02e38000, 0x04760000)
 total_blobs=4018 nmethods=3697 adapters=253 free_code_cache=25793Kb largest_free_block=26409280

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 10243.578 Thread 0x010eb400 3722             org.apache.http.message.HeaderGroup::getFirstHeader (52 bytes)
Event: 10243.579 Thread 0x010eb400 nmethod 3722 0x02e2ee48 code [0x02e2ef90, 0x02e2f130]
Event: 10243.604 Thread 0x010eb400 3723             com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl::appendChild (81 bytes)
Event: 10243.604 Thread 0x010eb400 nmethod 3723 0x02e2f288 code [0x02e2f3b0, 0x02e2f554]
Event: 10243.605 Thread 0x010eb400 3724             com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredAttrImpl::synchronizeData (86 bytes)
Event: 10243.605 Thread 0x010eb400 nmethod 3724 0x02e2f7c8 code [0x02e2f900, 0x02e2fb3c]
Event: 10243.605 Thread 0x010eb400 3725             com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredAttrImpl::synchronizeChildren (18 bytes)
Event: 10243.606 Thread 0x010eb400 nmethod 3725 0x02e2fcc8 code [0x02e2fde0, 0x02e2ff08]
Event: 10437.875 Thread 0x010eb400 3726             java.text.DigitList::set (174 bytes)
Event: 10437.876 Thread 0x010eb400 nmethod 3726 0x02e30008 code [0x02e30140, 0x02e30484]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 8439.874 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=38 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 27942K [0x04760000, 0x068c0000, 0x194b0000)
  eden space 27392K, 100% used [0x04760000, 0x06220000, 0x06220000)
  from space 3392K,  16% used [0x06570000, 0x065f9ae0, 0x068c0000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x06220000, 0x06220000, 0x06570000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 16162K [0x194b0000, 0x1d760000, 0x42f60000)
   the space 68288K,  23% used [0x194b0000, 0x1a478b68, 0x1a478c00, 0x1d760000)
 compacting perm gen  total 22016K, used 21876K [0x42f60000, 0x444e0000, 0x46f60000)
   the space 22016K,  99% used [0x42f60000, 0x444bd1d8, 0x444bd200, 0x444e0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 8439.876 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=39 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 565K [0x04760000, 0x068c0000, 0x194b0000)
  eden space 27392K,   0% used [0x04760000, 0x04760000, 0x06220000)
  from space 3392K,  16% used [0x06220000, 0x062ad6c8, 0x06570000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x06570000, 0x06570000, 0x068c0000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 16162K [0x194b0000, 0x1d760000, 0x42f60000)
   the space 68288K,  23% used [0x194b0000, 0x1a478b68, 0x1a478c00, 0x1d760000)
 compacting perm gen  total 22016K, used 21876K [0x42f60000, 0x444e0000, 0x46f60000)
   the space 22016K,  99% used [0x42f60000, 0x444bd1d8, 0x444bd200, 0x444e0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 8439.890 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=39 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 27957K [0x04760000, 0x068c0000, 0x194b0000)
  eden space 27392K,  99% used [0x04760000, 0x0621ff60, 0x06220000)
  from space 3392K,  16% used [0x06220000, 0x062ad6c8, 0x06570000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x06570000, 0x06570000, 0x068c0000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 16162K [0x194b0000, 0x1d760000, 0x42f60000)
   the space 68288K,  23% used [0x194b0000, 0x1a478b68, 0x1a478c00, 0x1d760000)
 compacting perm gen  total 22016K, used 21876K [0x42f60000, 0x444e0000, 0x46f60000)
   the space 22016K,  99% used [0x42f60000, 0x444bd1d8, 0x444bd200, 0x444e0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 8439.893 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=40 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 245K [0x04760000, 0x068c0000, 0x194b0000)
  eden space 27392K,   0% used [0x04760000, 0x04760000, 0x06220000)
  from space 3392K,   7% used [0x06570000, 0x065ad590, 0x068c0000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x06220000, 0x06220000, 0x06570000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 16163K [0x194b0000, 0x1d760000, 0x42f60000)
   the space 68288K,  23% used [0x194b0000, 0x1a478c88, 0x1a478e00, 0x1d760000)
 compacting perm gen  total 22016K, used 21876K [0x42f60000, 0x444e0000, 0x46f60000)
   the space 22016K,  99% used [0x42f60000, 0x444bd1d8, 0x444bd200, 0x444e0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 9976.704 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=40 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 27637K [0x04760000, 0x068c0000, 0x194b0000)
  eden space 27392K, 100% used [0x04760000, 0x06220000, 0x06220000)
  from space 3392K,   7% used [0x06570000, 0x065ad590, 0x068c0000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x06220000, 0x06220000, 0x06570000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 16163K [0x194b0000, 0x1d760000, 0x42f60000)
   the space 68288K,  23% used [0x194b0000, 0x1a478c88, 0x1a478e00, 0x1d760000)
 compacting perm gen  total 22016K, used 21878K [0x42f60000, 0x444e0000, 0x46f60000)
   the space 22016K,  99% used [0x42f60000, 0x444bd918, 0x444bda00, 0x444e0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 9976.707 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=41 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 593K [0x04760000, 0x068c0000, 0x194b0000)
  eden space 27392K,   0% used [0x04760000, 0x04760000, 0x06220000)
  from space 3392K,  17% used [0x06220000, 0x062b4748, 0x06570000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x06570000, 0x06570000, 0x068c0000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 16166K [0x194b0000, 0x1d760000, 0x42f60000)
   the space 68288K,  23% used [0x194b0000, 0x1a4798b0, 0x1a479a00, 0x1d760000)
 compacting perm gen  total 22016K, used 21878K [0x42f60000, 0x444e0000, 0x46f60000)
   the space 22016K,  99% used [0x42f60000, 0x444bd918, 0x444bda00, 0x444e0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 9976.720 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=41 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 27985K [0x04760000, 0x068c0000, 0x194b0000)
  eden space 27392K, 100% used [0x04760000, 0x06220000, 0x06220000)
  from space 3392K,  17% used [0x06220000, 0x062b4748, 0x06570000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x06570000, 0x06570000, 0x068c0000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 16166K [0x194b0000, 0x1d760000, 0x42f60000)
   the space 68288K,  23% used [0x194b0000, 0x1a4798b0, 0x1a479a00, 0x1d760000)
 compacting perm gen  total 22016K, used 21878K [0x42f60000, 0x444e0000, 0x46f60000)
   the space 22016K,  99% used [0x42f60000, 0x444bd918, 0x444bda00, 0x444e0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 9976.723 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=42 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 251K [0x04760000, 0x068c0000, 0x194b0000)
  eden space 27392K,   0% used [0x04760000, 0x04760000, 0x06220000)
  from space 3392K,   7% used [0x06570000, 0x065aefe8, 0x068c0000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x06220000, 0x06220000, 0x06570000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 16166K [0x194b0000, 0x1d760000, 0x42f60000)
   the space 68288K,  23% used [0x194b0000, 0x1a4798b0, 0x1a479a00, 0x1d760000)
 compacting perm gen  total 22016K, used 21878K [0x42f60000, 0x444e0000, 0x46f60000)
   the space 22016K,  99% used [0x42f60000, 0x444bd918, 0x444bda00, 0x444e0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}
Event: 10243.590 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=42 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 27643K [0x04760000, 0x068c0000, 0x194b0000)
  eden space 27392K, 100% used [0x04760000, 0x06220000, 0x06220000)
  from space 3392K,   7% used [0x06570000, 0x065aefe8, 0x068c0000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x06220000, 0x06220000, 0x06570000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 16166K [0x194b0000, 0x1d760000, 0x42f60000)
   the space 68288K,  23% used [0x194b0000, 0x1a4798b0, 0x1a479a00, 0x1d760000)
 compacting perm gen  total 22016K, used 21878K [0x42f60000, 0x444e0000, 0x46f60000)
   the space 22016K,  99% used [0x42f60000, 0x444bd938, 0x444bda00, 0x444e0000)
No shared spaces configured.
Event: 10243.593 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=43 (full 4):
 def new generation   total 30784K, used 556K [0x04760000, 0x068c0000, 0x194b0000)
  eden space 27392K,   0% used [0x04760000, 0x04760000, 0x06220000)
  from space 3392K,  16% used [0x06220000, 0x062ab348, 0x06570000)
  to   space 3392K,   0% used [0x06570000, 0x06570000, 0x068c0000)
 tenured generation   total 68288K, used 16166K [0x194b0000, 0x1d760000, 0x42f60000)
   the space 68288K,  23% used [0x194b0000, 0x1a479ab8, 0x1a479c00, 0x1d760000)
 compacting perm gen  total 22016K, used 21878K [0x42f60000, 0x444e0000, 0x46f60000)
   the space 22016K,  99% used [0x42f60000, 0x444bd938, 0x444bda00, 0x444e0000)
No shared spaces configured.
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 10243.602 Thread 0x49e0e000 Threw 0x058293c8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u4\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 10243.602 Thread 0x49e0e000 Threw 0x05829530 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u4\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 10437.833 Thread 0x49e0e000 Threw 0x058c7e90 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u4\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 10437.833 Thread 0x49e0e000 Threw 0x058c7ff8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u4\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 10437.834 Thread 0x49e0e000 Threw 0x058cf2d8 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u4\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 10437.834 Thread 0x49e0e000 Threw 0x058cf440 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u4\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 10437.834 Thread 0x49e0e000 Threw 0x058d0038 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u4\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 10437.834 Thread 0x49e0e000 Threw 0x058d01a0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u4\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 10437.875 Thread 0x49e0e000 Threw 0x058d1338 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u4\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715
Event: 10437.875 Thread 0x49e0e000 Threw 0x058d14a0 at C:\jdk7u2_32P\jdk7u4\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:715

Events (10 events):
Event: 10243.593 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 10243.593 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 10243.593 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 10243.593 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 10243.594 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 10243.594 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 10243.594 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 10243.594 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 10243.594 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 10243.594 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done


Dynamic libraries:
0x01330000 - 0x0135f000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x77990000 - 0x77b10000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll
0x76470000 - 0x76580000     C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
0x76750000 - 0x76796000     C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
0x754a0000 - 0x75540000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ADVAPI32.dll
0x76a80000 - 0x76b2c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcrt.dll
0x75440000 - 0x75459000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll
0x76350000 - 0x76440000     C:\Windows\syswow64\RPCRT4.dll
0x75070000 - 0x750d0000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SspiCli.dll
0x75060000 - 0x7506c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x76980000 - 0x76a80000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USER32.dll
0x752a0000 - 0x75330000     C:\Windows\syswow64\GDI32.dll
0x76190000 - 0x7619a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\LPK.dll
0x75340000 - 0x753dd000     C:\Windows\syswow64\USP10.dll
0x6f890000 - 0x6fa2e000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_41e6975e2bd6f2b2\COMCTL32.dll
0x75240000 - 0x75297000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHLWAPI.dll
0x751e0000 - 0x75240000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x76dd0000 - 0x76e9c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSCTF.dll
0x6eb10000 - 0x6ebce000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x6e290000 - 0x6e5da000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x71810000 - 0x71817000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x75460000 - 0x75495000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WS2_32.dll
0x76580000 - 0x76586000     C:\Windows\syswow64\NSI.dll
0x74d50000 - 0x74d82000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x77960000 - 0x77965000     C:\Windows\syswow64\PSAPI.DLL
0x71750000 - 0x7175c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x71430000 - 0x71450000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x71450000 - 0x71463000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x6eee0000 - 0x6eef4000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\net.dll
0x74bc0000 - 0x74bfc000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x71ff0000 - 0x71ff6000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x717f0000 - 0x717ff000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\nio.dll
0x6e640000 - 0x6e782000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\awt.dll
0x768c0000 - 0x7694f000     C:\Windows\syswow64\OLEAUT32.dll
0x76b50000 - 0x76cac000     C:\Windows\syswow64\ole32.dll
0x75540000 - 0x7618a000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SHELL32.dll
0x713f0000 - 0x71403000     C:\Windows\system32\DWMAPI.DLL
0x71420000 - 0x7142a000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\management.dll
0x6eeb0000 - 0x6eeda000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x74c80000 - 0x74d04000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.17514_none_ec83dffa859149af\comctl32.dll
0x6ea80000 - 0x6eb00000     C:\Windows\system32\UxTheme.dll
0x77040000 - 0x770c3000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CLBCatQ.DLL
0x6f280000 - 0x6f375000     C:\Windows\system32\propsys.dll
0x71bd0000 - 0x71bf1000     C:\Windows\system32\ntmarta.dll
0x75100000 - 0x75145000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WLDAP32.dll
0x761b0000 - 0x7634d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\SETUPAPI.dll
0x750d0000 - 0x750f7000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CFGMGR32.dll
0x76b30000 - 0x76b42000     C:\Windows\syswow64\DEVOBJ.dll
0x72710000 - 0x7275c000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6be40000 - 0x6bfd8000     C:\Windows\system32\NetworkExplorer.dll
0x6ee50000 - 0x6ee7e000     C:\Windows\System32\shdocvw.dll
0x74ae0000 - 0x74aeb000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x6e980000 - 0x6ea7b000     C:\Windows\system32\WindowsCodecs.dll
0x6ee00000 - 0x6ee31000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorShell.dll
0x6e850000 - 0x6e8c0000     C:\Windows\system32\ntshrui.dll
0x6ef10000 - 0x6ef29000     C:\Windows\system32\srvcli.dll
0x713e0000 - 0x713eb000     C:\Windows\system32\cscapi.dll
0x6ef00000 - 0x6ef0a000     C:\Windows\system32\slc.dll
0x6e940000 - 0x6e971000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\t2k.dll
0x6ee90000 - 0x6eea2000     C:\Windows\system32\MPR.dll
0x71730000 - 0x71738000     C:\Windows\System32\drprov.dll
0x73010000 - 0x73039000     C:\Windows\System32\WINSTA.dll
0x6e910000 - 0x6e924000     C:\Windows\System32\ntlanman.dll
0x71410000 - 0x7141f000     C:\Windows\system32\wkscli.dll
0x6ee40000 - 0x6ee49000     C:\Windows\system32\netutils.dll
0x6e8e0000 - 0x6e902000     C:\Windows\system32\EhStorAPI.dll
0x76950000 - 0x7697d000     C:\Windows\syswow64\WINTRUST.dll
0x76ea0000 - 0x76fbd000     C:\Windows\syswow64\CRYPT32.dll
0x75330000 - 0x7533c000     C:\Windows\syswow64\MSASN1.dll
0x6eb00000 - 0x6eb09000     C:\Windows\system32\LINKINFO.dll
0x72090000 - 0x72098000     C:\Windows\system32\Secur32.dll
0x6e8d0000 - 0x6e8df000     C:\Windows\system32\samcli.dll
0x6e830000 - 0x6e842000     C:\Windows\system32\SAMLIB.dll
0x74b20000 - 0x74b25000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x74c20000 - 0x74c64000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x74b90000 - 0x74bac000     C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x74b80000 - 0x74b87000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x74b30000 - 0x74b36000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x74b40000 - 0x74b78000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x6e810000 - 0x6e830000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\sunec.dll
0x72ff0000 - 0x73006000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x72fb0000 - 0x72feb000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x74af0000 - 0x74b07000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x74c10000 - 0x74c20000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x74c00000 - 0x74c10000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x74bb0000 - 0x74bb8000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x6e8c0000 - 0x6e8c9000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x6e7e0000 - 0x6e804000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\dcpr.dll
0x6e7d0000 - 0x6e7de000     C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\JdbcOdbc.dll
0x74df0000 - 0x74e7c000     C:\Windows\system32\ODBC32.dll
0x74db0000 - 0x74de8000     C:\Windows\system32\odbcint.dll
0x71d60000 - 0x71d77000     C:\Windows\system32\bcrypt.dll
0x71d20000 - 0x71d5d000     C:\Windows\SysWOW64\bcryptprimitives.dll
0x74d40000 - 0x74d49000     C:\Windows\system32\VERSION.dll
0x6e7b0000 - 0x6e7ce000     C:\Windows\system32\odbccp32.dll
0x6c090000 - 0x6c17b000     C:\Windows\system32\DBGHELP.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms100m -Xmx1000m 
java_command: C:\Program Files\iDATest\idamain.exe
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin
USERNAME=Administrator
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 11, GenuineIntel




---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.1 , 64 bit Build 7601 Service Pack 1

CPU:total 2 (2 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 15 stepping 11, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, tsc

Memory: 4k page, physical 8386884k(6648412k free), swap 16771916k(15279932k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (23.0-b21) for windows-x86 JRE (1.7.0_04-b22), built on May  3 2012 00:03:48 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Mon Jul 23 04:57:23 2012
elapsed time: 10439 seconds
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
```

means that it is a `native` function that segfaulted (rather than the JVM itself). Often this can mean you're using a buggy 3rd-party library containing native code. However, since the most recent Java stack frame is from the Java standard library, it looks like it's Oracle's fault.

So it looks like a bug in the Sun/Oracle JRE (particularly `net.dll`, which I *think* is supplied by the JRE, is calling something winsock in a way that causes a segfault). Please report this as a bug to Oracle at the URL specified. (It might also be a bug in MS Windows itself, but in that case Oracle can deal with forwarding it upstream.)

Comment: It looks like the PC is in the middle of a wide string, not in code - definitely a bad bug.